# Is magnetism a fundamental force based just in spin interaction?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin

I am learning about the real nature of magnetic interaction and I have always read that magnetism is an electrostatic effect. However, many books describe magnetism as the interaction of magnetic moments, which are just proportional to the spin. Therefore, what is the real nature of magnetism? Why can't we consider it as a fundamental force if it is related to an intrinsic magnitude called spin, as electric force is to the intrinsic magnitude called charge?

Answer (score -1):

The magnetic dipole of an electron is just as fundamental as the electric charge. An electron must be considered both an elementary charge and an elementary magnet.

After it had been explained for a long time that accelerated charges are the reason for magnetic fields of conductors, the alignment of the magnetic dipoles of their subatomic particles was assumed to be the reason for their magnetic field in permanent magnets.

The magnetic field is just as fundamental as the electric field. The latter can be recognised by the separation of the charges, the former by the orientation of the magnetic dipoles of the charges. The magnetic dipole in turn always points in the same direction as the spin. Your question is therefore understandable and can be answered in a certain sense with yes.